# aws vpc subnet design

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet

I'm asked to update our current aws vpc environment, our current vpc cidr is `172.30.0.0/24`,
below are subnets and avilability zones:

- `172.30.0.0/26`    - `public1`  - `az1`
- `172.30.0.128/26`  - `private1` - `az1`
- `172.30.0.64/26`   - `public2`  - `az2`
- `172.30.0.192/26`  - `private2` - `az3`

I'm not able to recreate the vpc because some other services have been deployed to them,
as you can see, in az2 and az3, there are only one subnet, and I want to add one subnet in az2 and az3

But I don't know how can I split it, could you please give some idea

Comment: You can't split a subnet if it has any resources in it.

Comment: I want add new subnet, do you know how to set the cidr for new subnet in the 2 az?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue. Go to AWS console, VPC and add new subnet to it.

Comment: You can have multiple subnets in each Availability Zone. What did you try and what problem are you facing?

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein, since I'm not familiar with vpc subnet part, the problem is the new cidr block, I don't know wha't the value of cidr_block for new subnet, like can I use `172.30.1.64/26` for new subnet at az2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I use 172.30.1.64/26 for new subnet at az2

Sadly, you can't, as your VPC cidr is `172.30.0.0/24`. Since you can't delete any of your current subnets, I think the best way is to [add new cidr to your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-vpcs.html#add-ipv4-cidr). You can add `172.30.1.0/24`, and then you will be able to create `172.30.1.64/26` subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [CIDR calculator](https://cidr.xyz/):

Your VPC `172.30.0.0/24` goes from `172.30.0.0` to `172.30.0.255`:

- Subnet `172.30.0.0/26` goes from `172.30.0.0` to `172.30.0.63`
- Subnet `172.30.0.64/26` goes from `172.30.0.64` to `173.30.0.127`
- Subnet `172.30.0.128/26` goes from `172.30.0.128` to `173.30.0.191`
- Subnet `172.30.0.192/26` goes from `172.30.0.192` to `173.30.0.255`

Therefore, the VPC range is full!